# Google Compute Engine auto scaling aspnet

Tags: asp.net, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I deployed an ASP.NET Framework GCE from the marketplace and am not sure how to get autoscaling to work? It seems like I would have to create a managed instance group from a template of the GCE instance. However, I am unsure how to create a template from a vm instance deployed from the marketplace.

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with Deployment Manager? Do you have the link to the marketplace product? I am not sure, but I don't think you can easily. You would need to modify the deployment file to add auto scaling. However, creating your own deployment using ASP.NET is easy. Is there anything special that this marketplace product offered?

Comment: You are required to sign in apparently to view it, but if you just search for `ASP.NET Framework` it is the only result. Visual Studio recommended that I use it. It has .NET Core support which is what stood out to me as my application is a ASP.NET Core app.

Comment: This marketplace product has SQL Express. This means that you would need to remove SQL Server before you could enable auto scaling. Unless you plan to deploy a static website that does not change, you will need a shared storage location for IIS. I recommend testing with this marketplace product and then building your own custom instance that can be auto scaled. Remember with auto scaling, anything your software writes to the disk drive will be lost on scale-up and scale-down.

Comment: For those interested, this is the link to see this marketplace product. Login is not required: https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/aspnet

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am not massivle confident with virtual machines, by `disk drive` do you essentially mean any files the sotware saves locally? Also, how does one build their own image or modify an existing one?

Comment: I cannot answer this in a single comment. Building an image is easy once you setup an instance exactly the way you want. However, you need to understand the basics of Google Cloud.

Comment: I only have experience with using existing images. I will do some further investigation! Thanks

Comment: Could you please post your latest solution in an answer so others will also benefit from that ? Thanks.

Comment: I haven’t had a chance to explore this any further currently

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is first take a snapshot of your application running on the instance. Next, you'll use that snapshot image to create an instance template. Afterwards, this template will be used to define an instance group which elastically scales based on certain thresholds such as CPU utilization, traffic, etc. Consult this documentation for a full detailed instruction guide on how to achieve this on an ASP.NET app.

https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/using-instance-groups

Comment: Cody, not that simple. This marketplace image has SQL. This does not lend itself to be autoscaled.

Comment: Where are you seeing that the marketplace image has SQL? Link me the marketplace image, please.

Comment: In the description: `Windows dev stack featuring IIS, SQL Express, ASP.NET, .NET Core`